# Receive array from JavaScript in Go

Tags: javascript, arrays, go, webassembly, language-interoperability

I'm trying to receive an array from JavaScript in my Go code

```
func knapsackWrapper() js.Func {
    knapsackFunc := js.FuncOf(func(this js.Value, args []js.Value) any {
        capacity := args[0].Int()
        weights := args[1].Get("Uint8Array")
        values := args[2].Get("Uint8Array")

        return Knapsack(capacity, weights, values)
    })

    return knapsackFunc
}
```

However, I got an error during the build. Is it possible to pass a JavaScript array to Go?

Comment: What is the err?